# Can I mixed use Scala ExecutionContext and Java ExecutorSerivce

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, future

I noticed that scala `ExecutionContext` has a `def fromExecutorService(e: ExecutorService)` which convert a Java ExecutorService to scala `ExecutionContext`.

Can I mixed use these two? i.e.,:

```
val someExecutorService = ....
val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(someExecutorService)

val javaFuture = someExecutorSerivce.submit(...
val scalaFuture = ec.submit(...
```

The reason I want to do this is that I need java Future's cancellation feature...but I'm not sure whether the mixed usage will cause any trouble(my confusion is that why scala's future is not cancellable while it's using executor service under the hood and java Future is cancellable)

Comment: Well **Java** `Futures` are not really _"cancellable"_ in the most common meaning of the word, they just kill / interrupt the underlying thread possibly leaking resources; which may be the reason **Scala** `Future` didn't add that. - About mixing, I think it should be fine, both are just submitting things to the same thread pool. - BTW, if you really need cancellation, why not using something more powerful like `IO` from **cats-effect** or **ZIO**.

Comment: That's part of the reason, the other main part is that the `Future` in Scala is just the read-side of the computation, as opposed to the write-side (aka `Promise`), so it's the responsibility of whatever owns the `Promise` to cancel the computation and fail (or not complete) the `Future`.

Agreed that it should be fine to cancel a Java future executing on the same EC.